# Lubuntu 20.04 LTS issue with app icon on tray bar

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, icons

As you can see in the image, i can't see the icon of the app "Kvirc"...

[image: Kvirc icon doesn't appear in the panel]

Comment: Inspect the file "/usr/share/applications/kvirc.desktop" . It should have an option like this : "Icon=" . What's the address or just the name in front of that ? If there's not any icon with that name within your "/usr/share/icons/" directory , you can manually download the [icon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/KVIrc_icon.svg/600px-KVIrc_icon.svg.png) , put it somewhere and change the address in front of "Icon" to point to the icon you've just downloaded.

Comment: I opened the file and there is only: `Icon=kvirc` Now I try to edit with some path of new icon downloaded

Comment: My Kvirc icons have [this structure](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/KKsyFznyKS/).

Comment: How about your kvirc.desktop file?

Comment: I also have: https://paste.ofcode.org/35VYHMQia3ErxEvPBBQjMpx

Comment: My kvirc.desktop file's "Icon" option is exactly as yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109100/discussion-between-tommy-and-parsa-mousavi).

Comment: I still yet not fixed this issue...